# How to Write in csv or Excel file using CSV module or Pandas by combining two lists into one In Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, csv

I've got two lists.

```
list1 = ['abc', 'bcd', 'efg', 'ijk', 'lpo']

list2 = [111, 222, 333]
```

**Sometimes list1 is more values than list2, and other times list2 is more values than list1.**

How am I able to write on a CSV File Like This.

```
abc 111

bcd 222

efg 333

ijk

lpo
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `itertools` `zip_longest` then `to_csv`

```
import itertools
pd.DataFrame(itertools.zip_longest(list1,list2)).to_csv('Your.csv',header=None, index=None)
```